# Not able to set chrome user agent from spec in protractor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a test where i need to launch 2 browsers, 1 with android user-agent and other with windows-mobile user agent. I have set android user agent in conf file. For windows mobile, i am trying following:

```
driver1 = new protractor.Builder()
.usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
.withCapabilities(protractor.Capabilities.chrome()).setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments("--user-agent=" + userAgent)).build();
```

On run, it says:

> Failed: chrome is not defined

Comment: I am still looking forward for any suggestion or help.